# Syntax of various vector mutating methods in C++

Tags: c++, stl

`Wallet` is a class that keeps track of currency. With a blatant disregard for proper object oriented programming practices, this class has a public `float amount` member that keeps track of how much money is in the wallet. It also has a public `buyCandy()` method that subtracts the amount of money necessary to buy some candy (1 money). This class has only one constructor that takes in an initial amount of money. There is no default constructor.

I am using this class as a conduit to ask questions about the syntax of STL, pointers/objects, methods, and generics in C++, because I am very confused in these subjects.

I can not find a ton of example code that mutates vectors inside of methods, or uses a class object as the type of a vector.

I am trying to create an `evilBanker` method that mismanages a bunch of wallets. Instead of using proper C++ conventions, we are actually going to do everything inside of the `main()` method. Here is the pseudocode for what I am hoping to achieve:

```
//comment lines will report the result that report should have if done on the vectors
func evilBanker() {
    create a vector of wallets 'liked' with no elements
    create a vector of wallets 'disliked' with 10 elements with -10 in their account

    float evilAccount = 0;

    //report liked = 0, disliked = -100, evilAccount = 0

    'embezzleMoney' for 10 money from all of the 'disliked' wallets and add it to evilAccount
    //report liked = 0, disliked = -200, evilAccount = 100

    use 'buyCandy' to make the last 5 of the 'disliked' wallets buy candy
    //report liked = 0, disliked = -205, evilAccount = 100

    'likeSome' for first 5 of the 'disliked' elements into the 'liked' vector
    //report liked = -100, disliked = -105, evilAccount = 100

    'moveToFavorites' the 1st element in the 'disliked' vector to the 'favorites' vector
    //report liked = -100 - 21 + 50, disliked = -105 - 21, evilAccount = 100

    make a new wallet 'lucy' with 100 money in her account
    add her to the favorites using the 'addToFavorites' method
    //report liked = -71 + 100 + 100, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100

    reset the 'disliked' accounts removing all trace that they ever existed
    //if possible 'disliked' would now be at an entirely new memory location
    //but not sure if this is possible to do within a method
    //report liked = 129, disliked = 0, evilAccount = 100
}

//Takes in the list of liked and disliked people and moves the first 'n' elements from the disliked list into the liked list
function 'likeSome' (likedVector, dislikedVector, n) {}

//Takes 'n' money from everyone inside of the vector and adds the money to the myAccount float
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'amount' field to do the subtraction
function 'embezzleMoney' (walletVector, n, &myAccount) {}

//Makes everyone in the vector within a range buy candy
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'buyCandy' method to do the subtraction
function 'buyCandy' (walletVector, lowerIndex, upperIndex) {}

//Adds 100 money to 'walletObjects' account then adds the wallet 'walletObject' to the 'walletVector'
function 'addToFavorites' (walletVector, walletObject) {}

//Moves the 'nth object from the dislikedVector to the likedVector and adds 50 money to its account
function 'moveToFavorites' (dislikedVector, likedVector, n) {}

//Deletes all of the wallets in the vector. 
//To be thorough this will even delete the vector passed into it and create a new vector object to replace walletVector
function 'resetBank' (walletVector) {}

//Report the sum of the accounts of everyone in the vector. 
//As a precaution it should be impossible to modify the vector or its contents inside of this method
function 'report' (walletVector) {}
```

I don't know how to properly code most of these methods in C++, so I am hoping that you will be willing to type up at least the function signatures needed for each of the methods, and explain your rationale.

I realize that the functionality of this class is ridiculous. It is just the best scenario I could use to ask all the questions I have about C++ syntax.

For all examples above, it would be great to see examples of as many valid ways to make the functions work.

Comment: Is like a class or a type?

Comment: Google came up with https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm

Comment: @JakeFreeman sorry I realize that was ambiguous. This whole question centers around the manipulation of two vectors of Wallet objects. their names are 'liked' and 'disliked'

Comment: This type of questioning is too broad and off-topic for StackOverflow.  Narrow the focus of your questions, and ask each question separately.

Comment: @EdHeal that tutorial while useful does not have a class as the type of the vector nor does it have many examples where the vector is mutated or passed in to a method.

Comment: @J.Doe - How many examples do you need? It demonstrates most (all?) of the methods for vectors. Why not just read the book? Why are you expecting somebody to type in the signatures for a bunch of methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `vector` can be declared with a size of 0, and of any type (except `auto)`, like this: `vector<SometypeHere> x`. If you want to add elements to the end, you use `push_back(E)`. To create a `vector` with an initial size, use `vector<SometypeHere> x(n);`

To give an example, I took the `likeSome(vector likes, vector, dislikes)` method:

```
void likeSome(vector<Wallet>& likes, vector<Wallet> dislikes, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) 
        likes.push_back( dislikes[i] );
}
```

For the method `resetBank`:

```
void resetBank(vector<Wallet>& wallets)
{
    wallets.resize(0);
}
```

For the method `embezzleMoney`

```
void embezzleMoney(const vector<Wallet>& walletVector, int n, float& myAccount)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<walletVector.size(); i++) 
    {
        if(walletVector[i].amount - n >= 0)
        {
            walletVector[i].amount -= n;
            myAccount += n;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more examples.

Comment: sorry I wrote the comment for that one wrong it should move it from the dislike vector to the likes vector however I am pretty sure I can see how to do that from this method you wrote. Could you show the embezzleMoney and resetBank methods as well please?

Comment: @J.Doe - Why do you not have a go? Or are you just running late with the homework?!

Comment: @EdHeal I realize this sounds like homework but it really is not. I actually have a Java final alter this week. That being said I will include my guesses shortly.

Comment: @J.Doe - Would it prudent to be trying to learn Java?

Comment: @J.Doe I added the two methods hopefully they help you understand vectors. Vectors are very similar to array lists in Java and close to regular Java arrays except they are mutable.

Comment: @JakeFreeman - Surely it should not be possible for values in a wallet to be negative?!

Comment: @EdHeal that is true I fixed it.

Comment: @J.Doe do you need any other examples of Vectors? I believe that a solid understanding of Vectors is key for C++

Comment: @JakeFreeman on the embezzle money function is there a way you can make it so that one could not add or remove elements from the passed in vector and only modify each of the objects inside of it?

Comment: @J.Doe similar to how Java has the `final` keyword C++ has the `const` keyword does precisely that, updating answer to reflect this.

Comment: Why are vectors not created with the new keyword?

Comment: @J.Doe this is because `new` is reserved for pointers and while I believe it is internally called, it is just a regular template object the code.

Comment: In the resetBank is there anyway to do it like `wallets = new vector<Wallets>();` rather than resize (I realize that resize would be a better option but just for example)

Comment: @J.Doe no because wallets is not a pointer type you could do wallets = vector<Wallets>() instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161072/discussion-between-jake-freeman-and-j-doe).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Wallet
{
public:
    float amount;

    Wallet(float initialAmount) : amount(initialAmount) {}

    void buyCandy() { amount -= 1.0; }
};

typedef vector<Wallet> WalletVector;

//Takes in the list of liked and disliked people and moves the first 'n' elements from the disliked list into the liked list
void likeSome(WalletVector &liked, WalletVector &disliked, size_t n)
{
    liked.insert(liked.end(), disliked.begin(), disliked.begin()+n);
    disliked.erase(disliked.begin(), disliked.begin()+n);
}

//Takes 'n' money from everyone inside of the vector and adds the money to the myAccount float
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'amount' field to do the subtraction
void embezzleMoney(const WalletVector &wallets, float n, float &myAccount)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < wallets.size(); ++i)
    {
        const_cast<Wallet&>(wallets[i]).amount -= n;
        myAccount += n;
    }
}

//Makes everyone in the vector within a range buy candy
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'buyCandy' method to do the subtraction
void buyCandy(const WalletVector &wallets, size_t lowerIndex, size_t upperIndex)
{
    for(size_t i = lowerIndex; i <= upperIndex; ++i)
        const_cast<Wallet&>(wallets[i]).buyCandy();
}

//Adds 100 money to 'walletObjects' account then adds the wallet 'walletObject' to the 'walletVector'
void addToFavorites(WalletVector &wallets, Wallet w)
{
    w.amount += 100;
    wallets.push_back(w);
}

//Moves the 'nth object from the dislikedVector to the likedVector and adds 50 money to its account
void moveToFavorites(WalletVector &disliked, WalletVector &liked, size_t n)
{
    Wallet w = disliked.at(n);
    disliked.erase(disliked.begin()+n);
    w.amount += 50;
    liked.push_back(w);
}

//Deletes all of the wallets in the vector. 
void resetBank(WalletVector &wallets)
{
    wallets.clear();
}

//Report the sum of the accounts of everyone in the vector. 
void report(const WalletVector &wallets)
{
    float total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < wallets.size(); ++i)
        total += wallets[i].amount;
    cout << total;
}

void report(const WalletVector &liked, const WalletVector &disliked, float evilAccount)
{
    cout << "liked = ";
    report(liked);
    cout << ", disliked = ";
    report(disliked);
    cout << ", evilAccount = " << evilAccount << endl;
}

void evilBanker()
{
    WalletVector liked;
    WalletVector disliked(10, -10);

    float evilAccount = 0;

    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // embezzle 10 money from all of the 'disliked' wallets and add it to evilAccount
    embezzleMoney(disliked, 10, evilAccount);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // make the last 5 of the 'disliked' wallets buy candy
    buyCandy(disliked, 5, 9);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // likeSome for first 5 of the 'disliked' elements into the 'liked' vector
    likeSome(liked, disliked, 5);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // moveToFavorites' the 1st element in the 'disliked' vector to the 'favorites' vector
    moveToFavorites(disliked, liked, 0);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // make a new wallet 'lucy' with 100 money in her account
    // add her to the favorites using the 'addToFavorites' method
    Wallet lucy(100);
    addToFavorites(liked, lucy);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // reset the 'disliked' accounts removing all trace that they ever existed
    resetBank(disliked);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);
}

int main()
{
    evilBanker();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
liked = 0, disliked = -100, evilAccount = 0
liked = 0, disliked = -200, evilAccount = 100
liked = 0, disliked = -205, evilAccount = 100
liked = -100, disliked = -105, evilAccount = 100
liked = -71, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100
liked = 129, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100
liked = 129, disliked = 0, evilAccount = 100
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/soa9Qw)

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Wallet
{
public:
    mutable float amount;

    Wallet(float initialAmount) : amount(initialAmount) {}

    void buyCandy() const { amount -= 1.0; }
};

typedef vector<Wallet> WalletVector;

//Takes in the list of liked and disliked people and moves the first 'n' elements from the disliked list into the liked list
void likeSome(WalletVector &liked, WalletVector &disliked, size_t n)
{
    liked.insert(liked.end(), disliked.begin(), disliked.begin()+n);
    disliked.erase(disliked.begin(), disliked.begin()+n);
}

//Takes 'n' money from everyone inside of the vector and adds the money to the myAccount float
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'amount' field to do the subtraction
void embezzleMoney(const WalletVector &wallets, float n, float &myAccount)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < wallets.size(); ++i)
    {
        wallets[i].amount -= n;
        myAccount += n;
    }
}

//Makes everyone in the vector within a range buy candy
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'buyCandy' method to do the subtraction
void buyCandy(const WalletVector &wallets, size_t lowerIndex, size_t upperIndex)
{
    for(size_t i = lowerIndex; i <= upperIndex; ++i)
        wallets[i].buyCandy();
}

//Adds 100 money to 'walletObjects' account then adds the wallet 'walletObject' to the 'walletVector'
void addToFavorites(WalletVector &wallets, Wallet w)
{
    w.amount += 100;
    wallets.push_back(w);
}

//Moves the 'nth object from the dislikedVector to the likedVector and adds 50 money to its account
void moveToFavorites(WalletVector &disliked, WalletVector &liked, size_t n)
{
    Wallet w = disliked.at(n);
    disliked.erase(disliked.begin()+n);
    w.amount += 50;
    liked.push_back(w);
}

//Deletes all of the wallets in the vector. 
void resetBank(WalletVector &wallets)
{
    wallets.clear();
}

//Report the sum of the accounts of everyone in the vector. 
void report(const WalletVector &wallets)
{
    float total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < wallets.size(); ++i)
        total += wallets[i].amount;
    cout << total;
}

void report(const WalletVector &liked, const WalletVector &disliked, float evilAccount)
{
    cout << "liked = ";
    report(liked);
    cout << ", disliked = ";
    report(disliked);
    cout << ", evilAccount = " << evilAccount << endl;
}

void evilBanker()
{
    WalletVector liked;
    WalletVector disliked(10, -10);

    float evilAccount = 0;

    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // embezzle 10 money from all of the 'disliked' wallets and add it to evilAccount
    embezzleMoney(disliked, 10, evilAccount);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // make the last 5 of the 'disliked' wallets buy candy
    buyCandy(disliked, 5, 9);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // likeSome for first 5 of the 'disliked' elements into the 'liked' vector
    likeSome(liked, disliked, 5);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // moveToFavorites' the 1st element in the 'disliked' vector to the 'favorites' vector
    moveToFavorites(disliked, liked, 0);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // make a new wallet 'lucy' with 100 money in her account
    // add her to the favorites using the 'addToFavorites' method
    Wallet lucy(100);
    addToFavorites(liked, lucy);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // reset the 'disliked' accounts removing all trace that they ever existed
    resetBank(disliked);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);
}

int main()
{
    evilBanker();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
liked = 0, disliked = -100, evilAccount = 0
liked = 0, disliked = -200, evilAccount = 100
liked = 0, disliked = -205, evilAccount = 100
liked = -100, disliked = -105, evilAccount = 100
liked = -71, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100
liked = 129, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100
liked = 129, disliked = 0, evilAccount = 100
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/ZLyzcj)

As demonstrated above, your "*As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector*" requirement can be a little unrealistic.  Although it *can* be accomplished (as demonstrated above), it *shouldn't* be done this way.

The problem is, when you access a `vector` through a `const` reference, it provides read-only (`const`) access to its elements.  That means if the vector holds actual objects directly, you can't normally call any non-const methods on them or modify their data members.  You would have to use risky `const_cast` type-casts to remove the `const`-ness, or declare the data members as `mutable`.  As you can see above, the latter can make `Wallet::buyCandy()` be an oddity - it is a `const` method that modifies the `amount` of the object it is called on.

To work around this *correctly*, while satisfying your requirement, you can change the code to use vectors containing non-const pointers to dynamically allocated objects.  Then you can have read-only access to the pointers themselves, while having writable access to the objects they point to, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Wallet
{
public:
    float amount;

    Wallet(float initialAmount) : amount(initialAmount) {}

    void buyCandy() { amount -= 1.0; }
};

using WalletPtr = unique_ptr<Wallet>;
using WalletVector = vector<WalletPtr>;

//Takes in the list of liked and disliked people and moves the first 'n' elements from the disliked list into the liked list
void likeSome(WalletVector &liked, WalletVector &disliked, size_t n)
{
    while (n > 0)
    {
        WalletPtr w = move(disliked.front());
        disliked.erase(disliked.begin());
        liked.push_back(move(w));
        --n;
    }
}

//Takes 'n' money from everyone inside of the vector and adds the money to the myAccount float
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'amount' field to do the subtraction
void embezzleMoney(const WalletVector &wallets, float n, float &myAccount)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < wallets.size(); ++i)
    {
        wallets[i]->amount -= n;
        myAccount += n;
    }
}

//Makes everyone in the vector within a range buy candy
//As a precaution it should be impossible to add or remove elements from the vector only mutate the objects within the vector
//Should use the 'buyCandy' method to do the subtraction
void buyCandy(const WalletVector &wallets, size_t lowerIndex, size_t upperIndex)
{
    for(size_t i = lowerIndex; i <= upperIndex; ++i)
        wallets[i]->buyCandy();
}

//Adds 100 money to 'walletObjects' account then adds the wallet 'walletObject' to the 'walletVector'
void addToFavorites(WalletVector &wallets, WalletPtr w)
{
    w->amount += 100;
    wallets.push_back(move(w));
}

//Moves the 'nth object from the dislikedVector to the likedVector and adds 50 money to its account
void moveToFavorites(WalletVector &disliked, WalletVector &liked, size_t n)
{
    WalletPtr w = move(disliked.at(n));
    disliked.erase(disliked.begin()+n);
    w->amount += 50;
    liked.push_back(move(w));
}

//Deletes all of the wallets in the vector. 
void resetBank(WalletVector &wallets)
{
    wallets.clear();
}

//Report the sum of the accounts of everyone in the vector. 
//As a precaution it should be impossible to modify the vector or its contents inside of this method
void report(const WalletVector &wallets)
{
    float total = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < wallets.size(); ++i)
        total += wallets[i]->amount;
    cout << total;
}

void report(const WalletVector &liked, const WalletVector &disliked, float evilAccount)
{
    cout << "liked = ";
    report(liked);
    cout << ", disliked = ";
    report(disliked);
    cout << ", evilAccount = " << evilAccount << endl;
}

void evilBanker()
{
    WalletVector liked;
    WalletVector disliked;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        WalletPtr w(new Wallet(-10));
        disliked.push_back(move(w));
    }

    float evilAccount = 0;

    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // embezzle 10 money from all of the 'disliked' wallets and add it to evilAccount
    embezzleMoney(disliked, 10, evilAccount);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // make the last 5 of the 'disliked' wallets buy candy
    buyCandy(disliked, 5, 9);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // likeSome for first 5 of the 'disliked' elements into the 'liked' vector
    likeSome(liked, disliked, 5);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // moveToFavorites' the 1st element in the 'disliked' vector to the 'favorites' vector
    moveToFavorites(disliked, liked, 0);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // make a new wallet 'lucy' with 100 money in her account
    // add her to the favorites using the 'addToFavorites' method
    WalletPtr lucy(new Wallet(100));
    addToFavorites(liked, move(lucy));
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);

    // reset the 'disliked' accounts removing all trace that they ever existed
    resetBank(disliked);
    report(liked, disliked, evilAccount);
}

int main()
{
    evilBanker();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
liked = 0, disliked = -100, evilAccount = 0
liked = 0, disliked = -200, evilAccount = 100
liked = 0, disliked = -205, evilAccount = 100
liked = -100, disliked = -105, evilAccount = 100
liked = -71, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100
liked = 129, disliked = -84, evilAccount = 100
liked = 129, disliked = 0, evilAccount = 100
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/ppInQO)